# Error: Unable to attach current thread to the Java VM

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have implement an APP with xamarin.forms.

And I tested it on Huawei-Y7(Android 8).

Sometime it just accidently crash.

Can anybody suggest how can I debug this error.

Or what would be the cause of this error?

Here is the log

Thank you

```
07-08 16:59:00.474 W/zygote  (32269):   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x0 self=0xb933dc00
07-08 16:59:00.474 W/zygote  (32269):   | sysTid=2155 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb94ff970
07-08 16:59:00.474 W/zygote  (32269):   | state=R schedstat=( 11723333011 5979893 98 ) utm=1134 stm=36 core=2 HZ=100
07-08 16:59:00.474 W/zygote  (32269):   | stack=0xb9401000-0xb9403000 stackSize=1022KB
07-08 16:59:00.474 W/zygote  (32269):   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
07-08 16:59:00.474 W/zygote  (32269):   native: #00 pc 002e5553  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+130)
07-08 16:59:00.474 W/zygote  (32269):   native: #01 pc 0038391f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+310)
07-08 16:59:00.474 W/zygote  (32269):   native: #02 pc 0037fe93  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread21ThrowOutOfMemoryErrorEPKc+94)
07-08 16:59:00.474 W/zygote  (32269):   native: #03 pc 001a3ce1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap21ThrowOutOfMemoryErrorEPNS_6ThreadEjNS0_13AllocatorTypeE+512)
07-08 16:59:00.474 W/zygote  (32269):   native: #04 pc 001aaa03  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap22AllocateInternalWithGcEPNS_6ThreadENS0_13AllocatorTypeEbjPjS5_S5_PNS_6ObjPtrINS_6mirror5ClassEEE+9270)
07-08 16:59:00.474 W/zygote  (32269):   native: #05 pc 0010a7af  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap24AllocObjectWithAllocatorILb1ELb0ENS_11VoidFunctorEEEPNS_6mirror6ObjectEPNS_6ThreadENS_6ObjPtrINS4_5ClassEEEjNS0_13AllocatorTypeERKT1_+1338)
07-08 16:59:00.474 W/zygote  (32269):   native: #06 pc 0038b003  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread24ThrowNewWrappedExceptionEPKcS2_+798)
07-08 16:59:00.474 W/zygote  (32269):   native: #07 pc 0037fec9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread21ThrowOutOfMemoryErrorEPKc+148)
07-08 16:59:00.474 W/zygote  (32269):   native: #08 pc 001a3ce1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap21ThrowOutOfMemoryErrorEPNS_6ThreadEjNS0_13AllocatorTypeE+512)
07-08 16:59:00.474 W/zygote  (32269):   native: #09 pc 001aaa03  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap22AllocateInternalWithGcEPNS_6ThreadENS0_13AllocatorTypeEbjPjS5_S5_PNS_6ObjPtrINS_6mirror5ClassEEE+9270)
07-08 16:59:00.474 W/zygote  (32269):   native: #10 pc 0010a7af  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap24AllocObjectWithAllocatorILb1ELb0ENS_11VoidFunctorEEEPNS_6mirror6ObjectEPNS_6ThreadENS_6ObjPtrINS4_5ClassEEEjNS0_13AllocatorTypeERKT1_+1338)
07-08 16:59:00.474 W/zygote  (32269):   native: #11 pc 00279149  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI11AllocObjectEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclass+516)
07-08 16:59:00.474 W/zygote  (32269):   native: #12 pc 000c5ddf  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI11AllocObjectEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclass+526)
07-08 16:59:00.474 W/zygote  (32269):   native: #13 pc 0038214b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread10CreatePeerEPKcbP8_jobject+194)
07-08 16:59:00.475 W/zygote  (32269):   native: #14 pc 003805bd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread6AttachEPKcbP8_jobjectb+312)
07-08 16:59:00.475 W/zygote  (32269):   native: #15 pc 00364961  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime19AttachCurrentThreadEPKcbP8_jobjectb+60)
07-08 16:59:00.475 W/zygote  (32269):   native: #16 pc 0024ada1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JII27AttachCurrentThreadInternalEP7_JavaVMPP7_JNIEnvPvb+212)
07-08 16:59:00.475 W/zygote  (32269):   native: #17 pc 000df829  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJII19AttachCurrentThreadEP7_JavaVMPP7_JNIEnvPv+84)
07-08 16:59:00.475 W/zygote  (32269):   native: #18 pc 0000e737  /data/app/com.mydeltasolar_1_0_1.app--E1ebwmEQ-Whx8VNV4x0OQ==/lib/arm/libmonodroid.so (???)
07-08 16:59:00.475 W/zygote  (32269):   native: #19 pc 001ecebc  /data/app/com.mydeltasolar_1_0_1.app--E1ebwmEQ-Whx8VNV4x0OQ==/lib/arm/libmonosgen-2.0.so (???)
07-08 16:59:00.475 W/zygote  (32269):   (no managed stack frames)
07-08 16:59:00.475 W/zygote  (32269): 
07-08 16:59:00.476 E/zygote  (32269): Exception creating thread peer:
07-08 16:59:00.476 E/zygote  (32269): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available
07-08 16:59:00.476 E/zygote  (32269): (Throwable with empty stack trace)
07-08 16:59:00.476 E/zygote  (32269): 
07-08 16:59:00.476 F/monodroid(32269): ERROR: Unable to attach current thread to the Java VM!
```

Comment: Based on your log `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available`,  it seems that lack of menory in your device.

Comment: If this was due to lack of memory, is there anything I can try to avoid it?

Comment: You can try to clean all the background application before your debug you application in this device, it this issue will occur fewer. If this issue is still existed, change a bigger RAM android and make a test.